# Logger command doesn't work in CentOS?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

I'm trying to use `logger` in my script 'cause `initlog` will be deprecated, but it seems not be working in CentOS 5.8 or I'm doing something wrong here.
I run this script with argument `stop` and check in `/var/log/messages` and it doesn't appear any log there. I tried in CentOS 6.4 and it works fine.

Here's part of my code:

```
stop() {
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # logging the stop
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  logger -i "Stopping $service" -t "$service" # it seems not be working

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # getting the process PID
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  pid_process=`ps -ef | grep "program.jar" | grep -v grep |awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'`;

  if [ $pid_process ]; then
    action $"Stopping $service: " su - program_deployer -c $shutdown
    RETVAL=$?
  else
    echo "#######################"
    echo "$service is not running"
    echo "#######################"
  fi

  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  # now, delete the lock file
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------
  rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$service
  echo
}
```

What is my mistake here ?

Comment: does a plain **echo test|logger** on the command-line write anything to syslog?

Comment: it's because of '-t' argument. Logger works fine without tag specified. Seems to be a bug in a 'logger'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me on CentOS 5.8 it worked as described above. I send all `*.info` messages to `/var/log/messages`.

You should check that syslog is correctly configured to send those messages to the correct destination, that syslog is running and that the `stop()` function is actually called.

I'm also assuming that `stop()` is called as root, because I can see that you do a `su - program_deployer` to shutdown the process.

Answer (score -4):

Try this,

```
 echo "Stopping $service" | tee -a /var/log/messages
```

Echo output appends to /var/log/messages.

Comment: Writing directly to system log files will fail for non-root users.